# Pi-Hole: How to block even more ads/DNS-Adresses with Wireshark?

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark

So I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 and on there a DHCP and Pi-Hole Server for ad blocking purposes. Websites like speedtest.net or n-tv.de are completely ad clean but YouTube for example isn't. I've tried adding RegEx filters, blacklist filters and adlists with no success. I'm aware of YouTubes erfforts in advertising but still shouldn't it be possible to capture DNS traffic over Wireshark and then add YouTubes advertisment DNS domains to Pi-Hole?

[Wireshark extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD997.jpg) (for me it seems like "googleads.g.doubleclick " still serves my computer with advertisement)

Maybe it is to complicated to block YouTubes advertisement but still my adblock plugin was capable of blocking at least some of YouTubes ads.

Edit: I have also blocked access to DNS service (53/udp) on any device in my local network except my Pi-Hole as it should handle all DNS traffic.

Comment: This question can't be answered because it's predicated on an incorrect premise. YouTube doesn't use different domains to serve advertisements. That's why you can't block their ads with DNS blocking/spoofing.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If u want an adblocker for all websites, use Brave, it has the most efficient adblocker ive seen, since i have it, ive only see ads if i deactivate it. It's really good. I dont know if its what you want but probably can do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
Yeah an AdBlocker thats what I used before but to also remove ads from ios apps, which also works just fine, I would like to use pi-hole. And it just would be great if it also worked on YouTube.